Metric completion of a metrizable topological vector space is a topological vector space
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a real topological vector space and let $d$ be a metric on $X$ which is translation invariant and induces the topology $\tau$.
Consider the metric completion $(\hat{X},\hat{d})$ of $(X,d)$; this can be quite easily endowed with a vector space structure. It is also easy to show that the metric $\hat{d}$ is translation invariant. I have however troubles showing that the scalar multiplication is jointly continuous i.e. that the map $(\lambda, \hat{x}) \mapsto \lambda \hat{x}$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R} \times \hat{X}$ to $\hat{X}$.
What is clear to me is that, for every fixed $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, the map $x \mapsto \lambda x$ is uniformly continuous as a map from $(X,d)$ to $(X,d)$ so that it extends continuously and uniquely to a map from $(\hat{X}, \hat{d})$ to $(\hat{X}, \hat{d})$. However the same does not hold for the map $(\lambda, \hat{x}) \mapsto \lambda \hat{x}$ so that I do not know how to proceed.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

The completion of topological vector spaces is, e.g., in Koethe's book Topological Vector Spaces, 15.3. As in the metric case that you consider, you take the the completion of the uniformity induced by the vectro space topology and show that the vector space operations extend continuously. But you are right, that this needs some care because multiplication $\mathbb R\times X\to X$ is not uniformly continuous.
